# Play Framework/Activator failing to resolve scalaz dependency

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

Play framework noob here. Have tried removing the `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2` folders but still beating around the bush while `activator clean eclipse` over a fresh local checkout of a bitbucket repository. I am expecting some environment issues since the same code is deployed live as well, however, have not tried building on the live server again (cannot for another couple of days).

Basically, a download of a particular jar file fails.

This is what I have already tried after going through suggestions from some googling:

1. Removed `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2` folders and built again
2. Changed scala version to a relatively newer one (2.11.6) in `build.sbt`

Following is the trailing output:

```
download failed: org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2!scalaz-effect_2.10.jar(bundle)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:217)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:126)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:103)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:48)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:98)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:94)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:115)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:125)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1223)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1221)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1244)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$74.apply(Defaults.scala:1242)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1246)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1241)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1249)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1214)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1192)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2!scalaz-core_2.10.jar(bundle)
[error] download failed: org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2!scalaz-effect_2.10.jar(bundle)***
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scalaz repository. In order to do that, just add the following line to your `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Comment: Doesn't work even with that resolver. And mysteriously, this only fails when I try to execute `activator dist` from within a docker image.